# SQL where clause include if clause fails

Tags: sql-server

My google foo is failing and I can't find an answer.
I have two tables, a seller table and a transaction table.
A seller may have multiple transactions or no transactions.
I want to output a single line for each seller, and if one they have a transaction type 101 output it along with the seller name. If not still output the seller but leave the transaction type null.

Current query:

```
SELECT        dbo.seller.de_name, dbo.de_transaction.tr_type
FROM            dbo.seller LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.de_transaction ON dbo.seller.de_rowid = 
dbo.de_transaction.tr_rowid_debtor
WHERE        (dbo.de_transaction.tr_type = N'101') OR
                         (dbo.de_transaction.tr_type IS NULL)
```

Bob Smith is outputting because he has a 101, Jane Doe is outputting because she has no transactions, but John Doe is not because he has a transaction, but its not type 101.
An SQL Fiddle will explain this better than I can.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/efc87/1

Thanks! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geez that was too easy.
I shouldn't have used a where clause.

```
SELECT        dbo.seller.de_name, dbo.de_transaction.tr_type
FROM            dbo.seller LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.de_transaction ON dbo.seller.de_rowid = 
dbo.de_transaction.tr_rowid_debtor AND dbo.de_transaction.tr_type = N'101'
```